# FOOEvent - Get Order Info (total, items, etc) in PDF Ticket

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize my PDF Ticket of FooEvent.
I want to show in the First page of Ticket the Summary of customers Order like:

 Order Summary:

• Adult Tickets x2

• Children Ticket x4
etc.

For Example like the Confirmation Mail of Woocommerce.

This is the code of my PDF Ticket Theme:

```html
<?php

    if ($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketButtonColor'] == "#55AF71" || empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketButtonColor']) || $ticket['name'] == __('Preview Event', 'woocommerce-events')) {
        $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketButtonColor'] = "#A31320";
    }

    if ($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketBackgroundColor'] == "#55AF71" || empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketBackgroundColor']) || $ticket['name'] == __('Preview Event', 'woocommerce-events')) {
        $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketBackgroundColor'] = "#cacaca";
    }

    if (empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketTextColor']) || $ticket['name'] == __('Preview Event', 'woocommerce-events')) {
        $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketTextColor'] = "#ffffff";
    }
    
?>

<?php if (!empty($ticket['ticketNumber']) && $ticket['ticketNumber'] > 1) : ?>
    <div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>  
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (((empty($ticket['type']) || $ticket['type'] == "HTML") && !empty($ticket['ticketNumber']) && $ticket['ticketNumber'] == 1) || (!empty($ticket['type']) && $ticket['type'] == "PDF") || $ticket['name'] == __('Preview Event', 'woocommerce-events')) : ?>

<?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketLogo'])) :?>
<div class="event_logo" style="max-width: 150px; padding: 20px 0 0 0; margin: 0 auto 20px auto; width: 100%; text-align:center;width:100%">         
    <a style="border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; color: #000000; display: inline-block;" href="<?php site_url(); ?>" align="middle">
        <img width="150" alt="Event Logo" title="Event Logo" src="<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketLogo']; ?>" align="middle" style="display:inline; text-align:center;">
    </a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketHeaderImage'])) :?>
<!--[if mso]>
    <br /><br />
    <table border="0" width="600" align="center" style="max-width: 600px;margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-top:10px solid #3b3e4b;"><tr><td>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
<div style="max-width: 600px; margin: 20px auto 0 auto; width: 100%; text-align:center;border-top:10px solid #3b3e4b;">         
<![endif]-->
    <img style="display:block;text-align:center;max-width:600px;width:100%" width="600" alt="Header Image" title="Header Image" src="<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketHeaderImage']; ?>" align="middle">
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
</div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>

<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="max-width: 600px;margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#ffffff"><tr><td width="10"></td><td width="460">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
<div class="two-column" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; padding:0; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>;">
<![endif]-->
    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:480px; float:left;padding: 0;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 24px; color: #17181d; font-weight: normal; line-height: 28px; margin: 0 0 5px 0; text-align:left;padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;">Hawaii Park: <b style="font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $ticket['name'];  ?></b></h1>
  
        <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketText']) || (!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayZoom']) && $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayZoom'] != 'off' && !empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsZoomText']))) : ?>
            <p style="font-size: 14px; color: #555555; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; text-align:left;padding: 0 15px 10px 15px;word-wrap:break-word">   
            <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketText'])) : ?>
                <?php echo nl2br($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketText']); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if((!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayZoom']) && $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayZoom'] != 'off' && !empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsZoomText']))) : ?>
                <?php echo nl2br($ticket['WooCommerceEventsZoomText']); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>   
    </div>
    <!--[if mso]>
    </td><td width="10"></td><td width="120">
    <![endif]-->
    
    <div class="column" style="width:100%;height:120px;max-width:120px; float:left;padding:0;background-color:#b91426">
        <img align="middle" style="border: 0; outline: none; display:inline; margin: auto; text-align:center; padding: 0" src="<?php echo $ticketIcon; ?>" alt="Ticket" title="Ticket">
    </div>
    <!--[if !mso]><!---->
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
    
<?php if((!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsLocation'])) || (!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsDirections']))) :?>


<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center" style="max-width: 600px;margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#eeeeee"><tr><td width="120">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
<div class="two-column" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; padding:0; background-color:#eeeeee; margin: 0 auto;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>;">
<![endif]-->
    <div class="column" style="height:100px;width:100%;max-width:100px; float:left;padding:0;background-color:#282d33">
        <img align="middle" style="border: 0; outline: none; display:inline-block; margin: auto; text-align:center; padding: 0" src="<?php echo $locationIcon; ?>" alt="Location" title="Location">
    </div>

    <!--[if mso]>
    </td><td width="10"></td><td width="460">
    <![endif]-->

    <div class="column" style="min-height:120px;width:100%;max-width:480px; float:right;padding: 0;">
        <h1 style="font-size: 18px; color: #17181d; font-weight: normal; line-height: 10px; margin: 0; text-align:left;padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;"><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsLocation']; ?></h1>
  
        <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsDirections'])) : ?>
            <p style="color: #777777 !important;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 14px;text-align: left;padding: 0 15px 0px 15px;">   
            <?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsDirections']; ?>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>   
    </div>
    
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
</td><td width="10"></td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayDateTime'] != 'off' || $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayBookings'] != 'off') :?> 


<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="max-width: 600px;margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#ffffff"><tr><td width="10"></td><td width="460">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!---->

<div class="two-column" style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; padding:0; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>;">
<![endif]-->

    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:480px; float:left;padding: 0;">
        <?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayBookings'] != 'off' && (isset($ticket['WooCommerceEventsBookingSlot']) || isset($ticket['WooCommerceEventsBookingDate']))) : ?>
            <h1 style="font-size: 18px; color: #17181d; font-weight: normal; line-height: 10px; margin: 0; text-align:left;padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;">
            <?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsBookingSlot']; ?>
            </h1>
            <p style="color: #777777 !important;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 10px;text-align: left;padding: 0 15px 0px 15px;">
            <?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsBookingDate']; ?>
            </p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsDate'])) : ?>
                <h1 style="font-size: 18px; color: #17181d; font-weight: normal; line-height: 10px; margin: 0; text-align:left;padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;"><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsDate'];
                if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsEndDate'])) : echo " - " . $ticket['WooCommerceEventsEndDate']; endif; ?>
                </h1>
            <?php endif; ?>    
            <p style="color: #777777 !important;font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 10px;text-align: left;padding: 0 15px 0px 15px;">
                <?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsHour']; ?>:<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsMinutes']; ?><?php echo (!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsPeriod']))? $ticket['WooCommerceEventsPeriod'] : '' ?>
                <?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsHourEnd'] != '00') : ?>
                - <?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsHourEnd']; ?>:<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsMinutesEnd']; ?><?php echo (!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsEndPeriod']))? $ticket['WooCommerceEventsEndPeriod'] : '' ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo (!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTimeZone']))? " " . $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTimeZone'] : '' ?>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?> 

        <?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketAddCalendar'] != 'off') :?>
        <div class="add_calendar" style="max-width: 160px;margin: 0 0 15px 15px;width: 100%;background-color:<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketButtonColor']; ?>;text-align:left;padding: 10px 15px;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>">
        <!--[if mso]>
            <table border="0" width="160" align="left" style="max-width: 160px;border-collapse: collapse;background-color:<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketButtonColor']; ?>;" bgcolor="<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketButtonColor']; ?>;"><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->  
            <a width="160" style="max-width: 160px;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;color:<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketTextColor']; ?>;font-size: 14px;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:14px" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=fooevents_ics&event=<?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsProductID']; ?><?php echo !empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeEmail']) ? '&email=' . urlencode($ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeEmail']) : ''; ?>&ticket=<?php echo $ticket['ID']; ?>"><!--[if mso]>&nbsp;<![endif]--><?php _e('Add to calendar', 'woocommerce-events'); ?>&nbsp;+<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;<![endif]--></a>
        <!--[if mso]>
            </td></tr></table>
        <![endif]-->

        </div>
        <?php endif; ?> 
    </div>


    <!--[if mso]>
    </td><td width="10"></td><td width="120">
    <![endif]-->
    


    <div class="column" style="width:100%;height:120px;max-width:120px; float:left;padding:0;background-color:#f5a600">
        <img align="middle" style="border: 0; outline: none; display:inline; margin: auto; text-align:center; padding: 0" src="<?php echo $timeIcon; ?>" alt="Location" title="Location">
    </div>
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>

<div style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; padding:3px 0; height:5px; background-color:transparent; margin: 0 auto;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>;">&nbsp;</div>




<?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketPurchaserDetails'] != 'off' || $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayBarcode'] != 'off') :?>
<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="max-width: 600px;margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#ffffff"><tr><td width="300"
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
<div class="two-column" style="page-break-inside: avoid;max-width: 600px; width: 100%; padding:0; background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0 auto;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>;">
<![endif]-->   
    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px; float:left;padding: 0;">
        <div class="barcode" style="padding: <?php echo (get_option('globalWooCommerceEventsEnableQRCode') == "yes" ? "0" : "30"); ?>px 48px;min-height: <?php echo (get_option('globalWooCommerceEventsEnableQRCode') == "yes" ? "220" : "110"); ?>;width: 206px;background-color:#ffffff;text-align:center;">
            <?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayBarcode'] != 'off') :?>
                <?php if(!empty($ticket['type']) && $ticket['type'] == "PDF") : ?>
                <br /><br />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <img style="border: 0;outline: none;text-align:center;" src="<?php echo $barcodeURL; ?>" alt="Barcode: <?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketID']; ?>" title="Barcode">
                <div style="color:#555555 !important;line-height: 16px;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;" class="ticket_detail_text"><font style="color:#777777 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#777777"><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketID']; ?></font></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--[if mso]>
    </td><td width="300" style="background-color:#282d33" bgcolor="#282d33">
    <![endif]-->

    <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;min-height:<?php echo $minHeight; ?>; float:left;padding:0;background-color:#282d33">
        <?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketPurchaserDetails'] != 'off') :?>
         <div class="ticket_details" style="padding:10px;background-color:#282d33;text-align:center;">
            <h3 style="text-align:center;color: #ffffff;font-weight: normal;line-height: 22px;font-size: 16px;margin: 0 0 10px 0;"><?php _e('Dettagli Biglietto', 'woocommerce-events'); ?></h3>
            <div style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;" class="ticket_detail_text"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999"><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeName']; ?> <?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeLastName']; ?></font></div>
            <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeTelephone'])) :?>
                <div style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;" class="ticket_detail_text"><font style="color:#999999 !important;text-decoration:none" color="#999999"><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeTelephone']; ?></font></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeCompany'])) :?>
                <div style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;" class="ticket_detail_text"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999"><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeCompany']; ?></font></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeDesignation'])) :?>
                <div style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;" class="ticket_detail_text"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999"><?php echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsAttendeeDesignation']; ?></font></div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if($ticket['WooCommerceEventsTicketDisplayPrice'] != 'off') :?>
                <div class="ticket_detail_text" style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999"><?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsPrice'])) echo $ticket['WooCommerceEventsPrice']; else if(!empty($ticket['price'])) echo $ticket['price']; ?></font></div>    
            <?php endif; ?>  

             <?php if(!empty($ticket['WooCommerceEventsVariations'])) :?>
                
                <?php foreach($ticket['WooCommerceEventsVariations'] as $variationName => $variationValue) :?>
                    <?php echo '<div class="ticket_detail_text" style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999"><strong>' . $variationName .':</strong> ' . $variationValue .'</div>'; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- SEATING --> 
            <?php if(!empty($ticket['fooevents_seating_options_array'])) :?>
                <?php echo '<div class="ticket_detail_text" style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999">'; ?>
                <?php echo '<strong>'.$ticket['fooevents_seating_options_array']['row_name_label'].':</strong> '.$ticket['fooevents_seating_options_array']['row_name']; ?>
                <?php echo '</font></div><div class="ticket_detail_text" style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999">'; ?>
                <?php echo '<strong>'.$ticket['fooevents_seating_options_array']['seat_number_label'].':</strong> '.$ticket['fooevents_seating_options_array']['seat_number']; ?>
                <?php echo '</font></div>'; ?>                                      
            <?php endif; ?> 

            <?php if(!empty($ticket['fooevents_custom_attendee_fields_options_array']) && (isset($ticket['WooCommerceEventsIncludeCustomAttendeeDetails']) && $ticket['WooCommerceEventsIncludeCustomAttendeeDetails'] != 'off')) :?>
                <?php foreach($ticket['fooevents_custom_attendee_fields_options_array'] as $custom_attendee_fields) :?>
                    <?php echo '<div class="ticket_detail_text" style="text-align:center;color:#999999 !important;line-height: 18px;font-size: 14px;"><font style="color:#999999 !important; text-decoration:none;" color="#999999">'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<strong>'.$custom_attendee_fields['label'].':</strong> '.$custom_attendee_fields['value']; ?>
                    <?php echo '</font></div>'; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
                            
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if mso]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>


<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" width="600" align="center" style="max-width: 600px;margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-top:10px solid #f5a600;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !mso]><!---->
<div style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; padding:3px 0; height:5px; background-color:#f5a600; margin: 0 auto;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>;">&nbsp;</div>
<![endif]-->

<?php if(!empty($ticket['type']) && $ticket['type'] == "PDF") : ?>
<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#b91426" align="center" style="max-width: 600px;margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;background-color:#b91426"><tr><td width="10"></td><td width="580">
<![endif]-->

<div style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%; padding:3px 0; height:5px; background-color:transparent; margin: 0 auto;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>;">&nbsp;</div>

<?php if(!empty($ticket['FooEventsTicketFooterText'])) :?>
<div class="footer" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color:#b91426; text-align:center; padding: 10px 0; font-size:11px; color:#ffffff;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>">
    <span style="padding: 0px 5px"><?php echo $ticket['FooEventsTicketFooterText'];?></span>
</div>
<br /><br />
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($ticket['name'] == __('Preview Event', 'woocommerce-events')): ?>
<div class="footer" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; background-color:#b91426; text-align:center; padding: 10px 0; font-size:11px; color:#ffffff;font-family: <?php echo $font_family; ?>">
    <span style="padding: 0px 5px"><?php _e('Contact us for questions and concerns.', 'woocommerce-events'); ?></span>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<?php endif; ?>
<!--[if mso]>
</td><td width="10"></td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I retrieve the Woocommerce order details and enter them here?

Comment: Did you have an answer.. i have the same issue!